# Simulate SOAP request with attachment in Karate

Tags: soap, karate

I am trying to simulate SOAP request with attachment in Karate. Following link provides [SOAP request details from SOAP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Rbp.png).

To simulate this in Karate, I have tried the following:
[Karate request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iek7F.png)

**Problem I am having:**

1. Getting 500 error

Below is the request and response log from Karate:

[Karate request and response log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2q8oipenkzndiwh/Karate_RequestAndReponse.txt?dl=0)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the way karate works is you need to form the XML to be sent, in the case of attachments, my guess is that you use Base64 to encode the binary / byte-stream. use some custom code for that (one time creation of a utility / function)